# What is the difference between the "Retro" and "Standard" version of Puppy Linux?

Tags: distributions, puppy-linux

In one of the [download locations for Puppy Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/quirky/precise-5.7.1/), two different ISOs are listed:

- `precise-5.7.1.iso` (156 MB)
- `precise-5.7.1-retro.iso` (200 MB)

What is the difference between these two versions?

Answer (score 2):

Primarily, the "Retro" version includes additional drivers for older computers, including analog modem drivers.[[1](http://puppylinux.org/main/Long-Term-Supported%20Puppy.htm)] Second, it includes Opera as additional browser for PCs with not enough RAM (256 MB or less) to run the default browser, SeaMonkey.

These features in the retro version add about 50 MB to the total file size; this amount is negligible on a burned CD, but keep in mind that it also takes up that much more space in RAM if you have the LiveCD set to load entirely into RAM.